# Joomla main content width

Tags: templates, joomla

I'm using [this template](http://www.themza.com/demo/joomla/flight-simulator-template.html).  I don't want the left & right hand columns available, I need to use the whole space for the main column. I've disabled every module in the left & right columns, the content is correct on the left side starting under pic1 but on the right side I've got this big space on the right side.  I've changed all my rightcolumn settings in template.css to width: 0px but still no luck.  Does anyone have any other suggestions for me please?

Comment: provide a link to the site you are talking about... otherwise it is just nearly impossible to give you answer...

Comment: @sra, the link is inserted on the words "this template", but in any case it is:  http://www.themza.com/demo/joomla/flight-simulator-template.html

Comment: did you use firebug? If not: [download it](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/firebug/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just a first quick guess:

In the index of your template, line 43-44

```
    <?php if($this->countModules('left') xor $this->countModules('right')) $maincol_sufix = '_middle';
      elseif(!$this->countModules('left') and !$this->countModules('right'))$maincol_sufix = '_big';
      else $maincol_sufix = ''; ?>
```

here the template detects which modules are active and seems to change the class suffix. Here you need to inject your own. Let me know if you need more help...

EDIT:

Your template uses the following style classes to change the mainbody:

```
#maincolumn {
float: left;
margin: 0 5px;
overflow: hidden;
padding: 0;
width: 530px;
}
#maincolumn_middle {
float: left;
margin: 0 5px;
overflow: hidden;
padding: 0;
width: 740px;
}
#maincolumn_big {
float: left;
margin: 0 5px;
overflow: hidden;
padding: 0;
width: 967px;
}
```

The last one should be injected if no left and no right modules are found. You may change the width of this one to see a effect.

Comment: thank you, I found it and took it out completely, no luck.  I will keep trying.

Comment: @wilest don't remove these lines!

Comment: @wilest you should also check if the template assign the last one. otherwise it seems that still have a right module active... As mentioned above, firebug will help you here

Answer (score -1):

In addition to setting the rightcolumn width to 0px, you also need to expand the `#maincolumn`. since you only want the one column, I would recommend changing `width:530px;` to `width:100%;` or something similar.  You can also remove the `float:left;` rule

Comment: -1 Joomla templates often depends on more than simply the css you see.

Comment: @hair raisin Thank you I've just done all that but still no result, any other ideas?  I will continue trying.

Comment: @sra Joomla templates aren't magic. if you change the display rules on the generated content, it will work just like anywhere else

Comment: Yes, that work on the fly... But they have often logic for choosing or manipulating styles...

Comment: What is the ID attribute of the center column?